# Making non-secure http requests in Android nativescript

Tags: javascript, android, angular, mobile, nativescript

I am trying to make an http request from nativescript to a regular http (not https) server.

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    this.http.request(
        "http://localhost:3050/register", 
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            })
        })
```

The request worked perfectly when made to an https server, but when made to an http server (which is the server I am currently running), it wouldn't work.

In iOS, I had to add the following in the info.plist file in order to allow the request to the http server, and after that it worked fine:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

However, in Android, the request is still not working, and I cannot find any documentation about changes I need to make in order to get the request working to an http server. The request is not even hitting the server.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Localhost means the device you are running on. When using Android your loopback address is no longer the standard 127.0.0.1 (a.k.a. ***localhost***) but something like 10.0.2.2 (it might differ depending on whether you are using AVD or GenyMotion)

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958955/4936697)

You can also [use similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39108388/4936697) for cross-platform solution

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I thought the problem was with https but I was wrong :P

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to work out what the heck was going on for hours!

Answer (score 2):

I modified the `AndroidManifest.xml` located in `app\App_Resources\Android\src\main` from

```xml
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

to

```xml
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

I added the last line: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Then it worked!

See: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/secure-your-mobile-app-securing-data-in-transit