# Nativescript localhost http call fails on iOS

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using Nativescript sidekick cloud build on windows to test my app on iOS - I have also connected my iPhone.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39108388/5468755) post I am sending my http requests to localhost but they keep failing with this error.

> Http failure response for http://localhost:52553/api/rewards/all: 0 Unknown Error
>   Error: Could not connect to the server.

Here is my implementation of rewards service

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { SimpleReward } from "../models/simple-reward";
import { take, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class RewardsService {

    private baseUrl = "http://localhost:52553/api/rewards";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAllRewards(): Observable<SimpleReward[]> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/all`;
        return this.http.get<SimpleReward[]>(url).pipe(
            catchError((e) => {
                console.error(e);
                return of([]);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Please guide what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Add NSAppTransportSecurity as by default non https are not allowed in ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `localhost` as an exception to your `app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist` file to allow insecure (non-HTTPS) communication with the `http://localhost` domain:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This is preferable to allowing insecure communication with *all* domains.

**EDIT:** Also, remember that you must rebuild your app after editing that `Info.plist` file! Its changes cannot simply be live-synced or hot module reloaded like JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added it but got the same error.

Comment: @shobhitvaish You'll need to rebuild the app after altering the `Info.plist`; did you do that? Can do a clean build to avoid doubt.

Comment: I tried clean build but no luck. I am sure my localhost is working

Comment: Wait a minute. You're running `localhost` on your desktop, aren't you? Try running the app on your simulator instead of a physical device: `tns run ios --emulator`. Your iPhone won't have access to your desktop web server's `localhost`. If you want to connect to that from your physical iPhone, you'll need to turn on web sharing on your desktop (maybe also disable a firewall port) and connect to a specific IP from your iPhone rather than `localhost` and provide the corresponding `NSExceptionDomains` entry for it.

Comment: I see. I am on Windows so I can't run on emulator. Let me try the second approach.

Comment: So I finally got it working. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the security or add localhost as exception in your info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

Comment: Tried - No luck :(